# Как сделать редирект в nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

Всем привет!

Раньше сайт ссылался на папку /ru и т.д.
Сейчас же сайт переделали, а старые ссылки остались в поисковиках, и при переходе по ссылке типа:

```
https://site.ru/ru/index.php?page=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3+%D0%B8+%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B
```

выдаётся ошибка "File not found."

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в nginx сделать редирект со всех страниц типа /ru.... перенаправлять на сам домен? Спасибо